# I add pagination in my data table but some columns data not search

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

In my model I am join other table `branch` after join my `from` `to` data are present but not search and other data search successfully.
[image: after join data show but not search]

view:

```
<section class="content">
              <table id="example1"  class='display dataTable'>
                <thead class="bg-info">
                <tr>
                  <th>Dispatch Challan No</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>From</th>
                  <th>To</th>
                  <th>Lorry No.</th>
                  <th>Pan Card</th>              
                  <th>Driver</th>
                  <th>Owner</th>
                  <th>Remark</th> 
                 </tr>
               </thead>
              </table>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#example1').DataTable({
          'processing': true,
          'serverSide': true,
          "bInfo": false,
          'serverMethod': 'post',
          'ajax': {
             'url':'<?php echo base_url();?>booking/dispatch_challan/DispatchChallanController/getData'
          },

          'columns': [
             { data: 'disp_ch_no' },
             { data: 'disp_ch_date' },
             { data: 'from' },
             { data: 'to' },
             { data: 'vehicle' },
             { data: 'disp_ch_pan' },
             { data: 'disp_ch_driver' },
             { data: 'disp_ch_owner' },
             { data: 'disp_ch_remark' },
          ]
        });
     });
     </script>
```

controller:

```
 public function getData()
  { 
           // POST data
           $postData = $this->input->post();
           $data = $this->dispatchModel->viewData($postData);
           echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

Model :

```
function viewData($postData=null){
     $response = array();
     ## Read value
     $draw            = $postData['draw'];
     $start           = $postData['start'];
     $rowperpage      = $postData['length']; // Rows display per page
     $columnIndex     = $postData['order'][0]['column']; // Column index
     $columnName      = $postData['columns'][$columnIndex]['data']; // Column name
     $columnSortOrder = $postData['order'][0]['dir']; // asc or desc
     $searchValue     = $postData['search']['value']; // Search value

    ## Search 
     $searchQuery = "";
     if($searchValue != ''){

         $searchQuery = " (b.disp_ch_no like '%".$searchValue."%' or b.disp_ch_date like '%".$searchValue."%' or b.disp_ch_from like'%".$searchValue."%' or b.disp_ch_to like'%".$searchValue."%' or b.disp_ch_lorryno like'%".$searchValue."%' or b.disp_ch_pan like'%".$searchValue."%' or b.disp_ch_driver like'%".$searchValue."%' or b.disp_ch_owner like'%".$searchValue."%' or b.disp_ch_remark like'%".$searchValue."%') ";
     }

     if($searchValue != '')
     $this->db->where($searchQuery);
     $records = $this->db->get('dispatch_challan b')->result();
     $this->db->select('bn.branch_name as from_branch_name,bn1.branch_name as to_branch_name,vn.vehicle_no as vehicle,b.*,vn.*,');
             $this->db->from('dispatch_challan b');
             $this->db->join('vehicle vn', 'b.disp_ch_lorryno=vn.vehicle_id','left');
             $this->db->join('branch  bn', 'b.disp_ch_from=bn.branch_id','left');
             $this->db->join('branch  bn1','b.disp_ch_to=bn1.branch_id','left');
             $this->db->where('b.status','active');

     if($searchValue != '')
     $this->db->where($searchQuery);
     $this->db->order_by($columnName, $columnSortOrder);
     $this->db->limit($rowperpage, $start);

     $records = $this->db->get()->result();

     $data = array();
     foreach($records as $record ){

        $data[] = array( 
           "disp_ch_no"          =>$record->disp_ch_no,
           "disp_ch_date"        =>$record->disp_ch_date,
           "from"                =>$record->from_branch_name,
           "to"                  =>$record->to_branch_name,
           "vehicle"             =>$record->vehicle,
           "disp_ch_pan"         =>$record->disp_ch_pan,
           "disp_ch_driver"      =>$record->disp_ch_driver,
           "disp_ch_owner"       =>$record->disp_ch_owner,
           "disp_ch_remark"      =>$record->disp_ch_remark
        ); 
     }
     ## Response
     $response = array(
        "draw" => intval($draw),
        "aaData" => $data
     );
     return $response; 
   }
```

Comment: Please add your datatable js code.

Comment: @bimalsharma added  datatable

Comment: In your $searchQuery , you need to include search conditions for columns corresponding to for and to

Comment: check columns `b.disp_ch_from` and `b.disp_ch_to` , it might be with wrong name or wrong alias.

Comment: @bharatparmar it is write

Comment: try `inner` join when joining with table `branch`

Comment: @bharatparmar in my `dispatch_challan` i have id of `from` and `to` as `disp_ch_from` and `disp_ch_to`  and my branch table i have name of that branch after join i give name as `from_branch_name` `to_branch_name`

Comment: @farhantechno all thinks are correct. Only check with your query in parts please check that.  i was printed your query here. check your where conditions.

Comment: SELECT `bn`.`branch_name` as `from_branch_name`, `bn1`.`branch_name` as `to_branch_name`, `vn`.`vehicle_no` as `vehicle`, `b`.*, `vn`.* FROM `dispatch_challan` `b` LEFT JOIN `vehicle` `vn` ON `b`.`disp_ch_lorryno`=`vn`.`vehicle_id` LEFT JOIN `branch` `bn` ON `b`.`disp_ch_from`=`bn`.`branch_id` LEFT JOIN `branch` `bn1` ON `b`.`disp_ch_to`=`bn1`.`branch_id`

Comment: WHERE `b`.`status` = 'active' AND (`b`.`disp_ch_no` like '%d%' or `b`.`disp_ch_date` like '%d%' or b.disp_ch_from like'%d%' or b.disp_ch_to like'%d%' or b.disp_ch_lorryno like'%d%' or b.disp_ch_pan like'%d%' or b.disp_ch_driver like'%d%' or b.disp_ch_owner like'%d%' or b.disp_ch_remark like'%d%')